# jQuery $.map works in IE8 but not IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & IE8, but the page also needs to work in IE7.  In code before the part that is causing the issue, I read some data in & build an array that is a `SELECT` statement.  In the section of code where I have an issue, I am doing the following:

```
var found = $.map( mySelArr, function(val) {
   return val.mySelID === zSelID ? val.mySelStatement: null;
   });
```

I then reference it:

```
var selStmt = found[0];
```

(there will be only 1 returned, and I know it will be in the array).

In IE7, I saw that it is throwing an exception inside jquery.js.  When I step through debug on it, I see that the found length is zero (in IE7).  If I change the mode to IE8, everything works fine.  But in IE7, nothing gets put into the `found` variable.

What am I doing wrong to not be able to get this array value out in IE7?  Would appreciate any thoughts.

**EDIT**

mySelArr is an array of Select statements, similar to:

```
1,<select name='mySelID_1' id='plist' ><option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value='0'>Select Action</option><option value="1">This one</option><option value="2">That one</option></select>
```

and so on.

**EDIT 2**

I may have stumbled on the issue.

The array that held the select statements was being populated correctly in IE8, but not in IE7.

I actually had 2 arrays, one being just a number, and the other being that same number + the Select statement.  The array that had the index & select statement was built using:

```
arr1.push({ fld1:data1, fld2:selstmt})
```

The one with just numbers was built using:

```
arr2.push(arrndx)
```

The arr2 was the outer FOR, the arr1 was the inner FOR.  I had been referring to the number index by using:

```
var z = arr2[x][0];
```

to get the number & then using that to loop thru arr1 to get everything matching it & building the Select statement. What I discovered was that IE7 was returning `undefined` in the line of code above, while IE8 was returning the number (Firefox also).

I changed 2 lines of code to fix the issue:

```
FROM   arr2.push(arrndx) 
TO     arr2.push( {arrindex: arrndx} );
```

and

```
FROM   arr2[x][0]
TO     arr2[x].arrindex
```

and it works in both IE7 & IE8.  IE7 didn't have a problem creating that array, or reading it - it just wasn't valid data in it because of how I attempted to reference the fields in it.

I'm not exactly sure why IE7 had a problem with it & IE8 didn't, but....   Also, the fix didn't appear to break anything else.

Comment: When I try to run this to create a test case, I get `Unexpected token :` because of this part: `val:mySelStatement: null;` You can only have one "else" in the ternary operator.

Comment: see edited problem for example of contents of mySelArr.  @JasonP - I tried that, but it's not returning anything either.

Comment: Did you mean to write `return val.mySelID === zSelID ? val.mySelStatement: null;`

Comment: so you have a property named mySelID which is not in that example you gave? SHouldn't `val:mySelStatement` be `val.mySelStatement`. Your question is missing a lot of context, makes it hard to give you answer.

Comment: @StephenThomas yes, in IE8 that statement would return the content that is my select statement that I gave the example of when I reference `found[0]`.  IE7 throws an error because there's nothing in it.

Comment: @epascarello - thanks - typo in the statement has been corrected.

Comment: Another case of IE  id and names bug ?

Comment: For the record, there are a LOT of things that work in IE8 that don't in IE7.  I spent LOADS of time getting clone() to work.

Comment: I may have stumbled onto the actual issue.  See edit above.